# Python function general design practice - arguments and validation

Tags: python, function, validation, runtime

I used to program c++ and am looking for python newbies guides to design a python function. In c++, function has its own signature and type check at compile time, such that any misuse or wrong argument type could be noticed and we avoid runtime error.

What is the best practice writing a python function to avoid those careless mistakes? (e.g. wrong argument time, number of arguments mismatch). Thanks in advance for any good reference materials talking about this topic.

Comment: Python allows optional type annotations. But I think most programmers don't use them.

Comment: Those annotations don't enforce anything, though.

Comment: do you mean  function """doc string """?